# Python decorator class with function counter variable

Tags: python, class, object, decorator

I have class in Python which I need to use as a decorator class but I want to count something when it is called:

```
class SomeClass:

    counter = 0

    @staticmethod
    def some_function(a):
        """
        -----------------------
        Does something
        -----------------------
        """
        SomeClass.counter += 1
        a = a * a
        return a
```

after calling:

```
a = new_var.some_function(a)
```

how do I then get the counter value from my decorator class?

Comment: I think you mean variable instead of constant, since constants should not change.

Comment: `SomeClass.constant`?

Comment: static methods don't take self as an argument.

Comment: What is it that makes your class a decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you have shown us is *not* a decorator -- it is simply a class.  Accessing the counter is as easy as

```
SomeClass.counter
# current counter value
```

Making your class an actual decorator is not difficult -- I'll rename it to `Counter`, however.

```
class Counter:
    """
    Count the number of calls made to the wrapped function.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.counter = 0
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwds)

@Counter
def square(n):
    return n * n
```

and in use:

```
square(3)
# 9
square(7)
# 41
square(11)
# 121

square.counter
# 3
```

Note:  This is a very simple decorator, and one side-effect is that the signature of the wrapped function is lost.

the unwrapped signature:

```
Help on function square in module __main__:
square(n)
```

the wrapped signature:

```
Help on instance of Counter in module __main__:
class Counter
 |  Count the number of calls made to the wrapped function.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
 |  
 |  __init__(self, func)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you want to count. For example:

```
>>> class A(object):
>>>     pass
>>> ...
>>> def foo(obj):
>>>     def inner(*args, **kwargs):
>>>         counter += 1
>>>         print "times called: %d" % counter
>>>     counter = 0
>>>     return inner

>>> Bar = A()
>>> Bar.eggs = foo(Bar)
>>> Bar.foo()
times called: 1
>>> Bar.foo()
times called: 2
>>> Spam = A()
>>> Spam.eggs = foo(Spam)
>>> Spam.eggs()
times called: 1
```

This works because the wrapper will carry its environment around with it, which means `counter` is in scope of any given instance of `an_object.foo` when it is wrapped. Though it may not be as introspective as you would need.
Or, do you mean to count the total number of times `obj.foo` is actually called?